# Python code to close tkinter pop up window without killing the actual program

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm new to Python and with help from here I have drafted a code that gets input from a user and pass it on to other programs.

is there a way to close the pop up window without actually terminating or closing the program. I tried using Destroy() but it either just clears the content of the pop up message or messes the whole code.

Could somebody help me out here please. Below is the code I drafted.

```
import openpyxl
import tkinter as tk
class App(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
                self.answers = {}
                tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
                tk.Label(self,text="Give Input Sheet Path").grid(row=0,column=0)
                self.Input_From_User1 = tk.Entry(self)
                self.Input_From_User1.grid(row=0,column=1)
                tk.Label(self,text="Give Output Sheet Path").grid(row=1,column=0)
                self.Input_From_User2 = tk.Entry(self)
                self.Input_From_User2.grid(row=1,column=1)
                tk.Button(self,text="Feed into Program",command = self.collectAnswers).grid(row=2,column=1)
        def collectAnswers(self):
                self.answers['Input_Path'] = self.Input_From_User1.get()
                self.answers['Output_Path'] = self.Input_From_User2.get()
                print("Given Input Path ", self.answers['Input_Path'])
                print("Given Output Path ", self.answers['Output_Path'])
                global Input_Path
                global Output_Path
                Input_Path = self.answers['Input_Path']
                Output_Path = self.answers['Output_Path']
def main():
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("300x100")
        App(root).grid()
        root.mainloop()
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path)
        return wb["Sheet1"]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you want to "hide" the window instead of destroy it you can use the withdraw() method  and deiconify() to bring it back at anytime.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is for the TK window to "go away" without actually closing, you could use the `iconify()` method instead of `destroy()`; this will minimize the `App()` window to the taskbar without actually closing it.

I added `self.iconify()` to the end of your `collectAnswers()` method.

I also took the liberty of making some changes to your code's style to better align with standard Python style practices - if you aren't already using a linter like Flake8 or a formatter like Black, I would recommend doing so! Better to get used to having a style guide enforced before you develop bad habits!

```
import openpyxl
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):  # root application instance
    def __init__(self,**kw) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("300x100")
        self.title = ("Enter Sheet Paths")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.grid()
        input_label = tk.Label(
            self,
            text="Give Input Sheet Path"
        )
        input_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.Input_From_User1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input_From_User1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
        output_label = tk.Label(
            self,
            text="Give Output Sheet Path"
        )
        output_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.Input_From_User2 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Input_From_User2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        submit = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Feed into Program",
            command=self.collect_answers
        )
        submit.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.answers = {}
        
    def collect_answers(self) -> None:
        self.answers['Input_Path'] = self.Input_From_User1.get()
        self.answers['Output_Path'] = self.Input_From_User2.get()
        print("Given Input Path ", self.answers['Input_Path'])
        print("Given Output Path ", self.answers['Output_Path'])
        input_path = self.answers['Input_Path']
        output_path = self.answers['Output_Path']
        self.iconify()  # MINIMIZE THE WINDOW


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(Input_Path)
    return wb["Sheet1"]

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ,thanks for your comment :) . I took your code and  added input_path and output_path as global variable since I need to use them in other programs as well and after entering the Input_sheet/output_sheet value, the pop up window is minimised but its not being passed onto actual main program. I added a Print(input_path) statement in the main() just to check if its working but its not printing anything :(. Could you advise

Comment: Well, part of the trouble is that your `main()` function won't return anything until the TK app instance is closed - which is to say, `main()` gets as far as `app.mainloop()` and then _stays there_ as long as your TK app is running; the value of `wb` is never set and `return` is never called! I can't test a solution right now, but I believe the solution you're after is the tkinter `wait_window()` method. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-does-the-wait-window-method-do-in-tkinter) for more info on this.